Good screen recorder with Audio for Ubuntu 22.04
I have tried numerous option at Ubuntu 22.04 for recording my screen with voice but they all had some issue or the other.
Software tried are VokoscreenNG and Simple Screen Recorder. I have observed that audio recording is not good in these.
Also tried the inbuilt screen recorder (screencast) but it does not record audio.
Please suggest some good software for recording screen with audio.
Purpose is to record my screen for creating educational videos.

What does "not good" mean? You should be way more detailed.

You didn't try the by far most popular option - OBS Studio.
To get the best audio results:

add proper source for your input device, e.g. microphone
add filters to the created source to process the audio on the fly, e.g. remove noise, add some gain and limit max dB treshold. There are lots of videos on e.g. YouTube explaining how to properly set up filters.
add any other sources for whatever you want to record, specific windows are recommended. If you need other sound from e.g. the system, using Application Audio Capture source is recoomended for the best control.

